# COG tiff reports valid from gdal but does not load in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have a normal geotiff that i've converted to a Cloud Optimized GeoTiff (COGtiff) via GDAL 3.2:

```
$ gdal_translate image.tif image-COG.tif -of COG
```

it validates successfully with '[validate_cloud_optimized_geotiff.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentsarago/gdal/master/gdal/swig/python/samples/validate_cloud_optimized_geotiff.py)'

```
$ python3 validate_cloud_optimized_geotiff.py image-COG.tif
```

> image-COG.tif is a valid cloud optimized GeoTIFF . The size of all IFD headers is 2530899 bytes

But when I try to load this image-COG.tif (hosted on an AWS S3 bucket) into QGIS, it **doesn't show the 'Options' when I supply the file in the dialogue, so I can't click 'Add'**.

A COG that someone else produced via this great [COG Tutorial](https://www.cogeo.org/qgis-tutorial.html) loads successfully into QGIS 3.2 and shows the 'Options' section in the dialogue when I supply the filepath:

[image: qgis load COG options dialogue is shown]

Is there something I'm missing on the GDAL COG translation that is necessary for QGIS to be able to load it?

Comment: Is your bucket/that COG url public or do you need to supply authentication? QGIS 3.2 is very old suggest you upgrade to latest 3.24 or whatever the latest LTR version is. In 3.24 I do not get the GDAL options shown when loading the COG from the tutorial  but can still click Add. If you use the File: source type instead of HTTP/HTTPS/FTP and prepend `/vsicurl/` to the COG url, QGIS shows the [GDAL options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N50Ao.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not supply authentication creds in the Raster>Add dialogue, and then supply a cogtiff link (on AWS S3 in this case) which is ***not*** publicly accessible, the Options will not show and the dataset cannot be added to the map.

Qgis appears to be caching this url as 'invalid', so even if you modify the S3 privileges to make the image public, it still will not show the options and cannot be added to the map.

*Simply rename the image* within S3, and then the new URL will show the options in qgis and the cogtiff can be added to the map.